# How to maximize any of the views in quad view?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, shortcut

I am new to blender. Pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> opens the quad view. How to maximize any one of the four views of the quad view?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31221/how-to-maximize-a-view-ex-front-ortho-in-blender check this, it has the option ..

Comment: Can you set it up so you can use space key to toggle between quad and perspective view and hit space key again to select one of the 4 views and maximize it?

Answer (score 6):

The quad view exists so that you can see all the views at once.

Instead of thinking of it like maximizing one of the quad view windows, think of it like aligning the user controlled view to an axis.

- <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> snaps user controlled view to front view
- <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> snaps user controlled view to side view
- <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> snaps user controlled view to top view

Holding <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> will snap to the opposite direction of the axis, so <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> snaps to bottom view.

<kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> toggles perspective/orthographic view.

Also see [the wiki](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/navigation.html#navigation) for more information on navigating the 3D view.

Comment: Oops, my bad about shift.. good catch, thanks :) Not sure what you mean by the first point, you can't change the other views in quad view..? Edited to hopefully make more clear.

Comment: From your edit you seem to have figured out what I meant.

Answer (score 6):

To maximize a view you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>up arrow</kbd>, to get back to normal use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>down arrow</kbd>.  Make sure the cursor is in the view you want to maximize.

Most of the time I just use the numpad hotkeys gandalf3 mentioned though.

This does not work for the actual "quad view" in a single viewing window.  Instead of using the <kbd>Ctrl.</kbd> + <kbd>Alt.</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> quad view, I usually just set up a manual quad view using multiple viewing windows by dragging the little slanted lines at the top right corner of the view.  Then the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>up arrow</kbd>/<kbd>down arrow</kbd> will work.  You can make preset views by clicking the "+" at the top of the window (where it says "Default" now).