# How to maximize a view from quad view (ex. front ortho)?

Tags: interface, 3d-view

After I toggle the quad view, how can I maximize the front or any other ortho views? Just the CTRL + Up only hides some panels but it doesn't maximizes the view completely like the perspective view gets maximized.

Comment: to change the default settings of quad vie read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18320/how-to-change-the-default-views-of-quad-view

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Quad View, you have to toggle off the **Lock** button first, then move the mouse cursor over one of the four views, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Q</kbd> again.

[image]

Comment: Didn't see cegaton's comment linked to an already answerd question... This question is sort of duplicate indeed. Whatever, here is just a simple GIF for a quick illustration.

Comment: It's not a dupllicate, just related.

Comment: Right. Fairly related  :)