# Window min max when switching viewports?

Tags: 3d-view

I am looking for a way to toggle from the quad viewport (top,left,front,persp etc) to making one viewport larger Blender 2.8 is amazing but the hotkeys and viewport navigation is not intuitive.

This is an example in Silo: Here I have a quad viewport and I moused over to perspective and hit spacebar and it went full display in quad layout. From there I can hit spacebar again and mouse over another view, hit spacebar again and can toggle back and forth. Does Blender have that ability or is it something I might have to script in Python?

[image]

Comment: in Blender it's CTRL+spacebar and no offense, but I think you're confusing "intuitive" with "what I'm already used to"

Comment: Think the point was missed. Thank you for the answer but I am asking about switching viewports to min max. what I have seen is you can max perspective and have to use NUM keys in that port to go top,left,bottom etc. Your answer only maximizes and hides properties, animation and menu bars. No offense but people keep missing what I am trying to get help with.

Comment: right, then sorry, I thought that was what you meant by "min/max viewport", but obviously not. Can you try to describe a bit more what you're after?

Comment: Hi, ok here it is: I am in quad view, and am looking for a way to go let's say switch to 'top' viewport.. now I want to make that viewport full view. then do my editing, switch back to quad and now I would like to go to 'left' viewport and make that full view, etc, The only thing I could use so far would be in quad view and the perspective viewport can be made full and can only toggle left,top,bottom etc with the gizmo. thanks for helping me so far.

Comment: okay, then there isn't really an equivalent in Blender (apart from CTRL+ALT+Q to get in and out of quad view). You might be better off splitting your viewport in 4 (by dragging the corners) and setting each view manually then using CTRL+spacebar to max them

Comment: this sounds like what you need: [How to maximize a view from quad view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31221/how-to-maximize-a-view-ex-front-ortho-in-blender) Unock the view and then use Ctr+Alt+Q

Comment: @susu I was writing a comment to say just that :) Also, you can remap that shortcut (preferences>keymap>search for "quad") to something easier to reach, like say CTRL+\

Comment: Holy, the moderators and Stack are ridiculously nit picky about posts. This is a question and answer type of website(s) and if am getting character deleted and flagged I will go somewhere else. I said nothing out as I believe 'wrong' or inflammatory. I will go elsewhere to talk about Blender and help in migrating from other applications to working now in Blender. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Nothing personal, I'm pretty sure it's just to avoid duplicate questions, same as on any other stackexchange sites (which are quite different from forums or quora). Maybe try https://blenderartists.org/ for a more casual time. The big shame is that it was flagged as a duplicate of a question that doesn't have a good answer, when the one susu pointed out is way better! https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31221/how-to-maximize-a-view-ex-front-ortho-in-blender

Comment: Nothing personal but your guys are total jerks. I did NOTHING wrong, was not mean, abusive and feel like I have to walk on eggshells on these sites. Find someone to delete all my info as I couldn't find it from digging around of the Stack master sites. I am very disappointed in how this Stack site operates. I am spreading the word to have anyone I know to never signup for your services.

Comment: related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18320/how-to-change-the-default-views-of-quad-view