# Can the sections of quad view be enlarged?

Tags: python

I can do Quad View Display with ctrl+Alt+Q

Can any of the sections be enlarged or be broader?

Is that possible?

Comment: related?: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16505/how-to-maximize-any-of-the-views-in-quad-view and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31221/how-to-maximize-a-view-ex-front-ortho-in-blender and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18320/how-to-change-the-default-views-of-quad-view

Comment: or: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57102/how-do-i-achieve-the-tri-view-in-blender